# NSPredicate performance, very slow

Tags: xcode, core-data, nspredicate

I have an NSPredicate which looks like

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((strasse.checks CONTAINS [cd] YES) AND (raumattribute.schalter CONTAINS[cd] YES)) OR ((strasse.standort.ortcheck CONTAINS [cd] YES) AND (raumattribute.schalter CONTAINS[cd] YES)) OR ((strasse.standort.ortcheck CONTAINS [cd] YES) AND(raumattribute.schalter CONTAINS[cd] NO) OR (strasse.checks CONTAINS [cd] YES) AND (raumattribute.schalter CONTAINS[cd] NO)) OR (strasse.standort.ortcheck CONTAINS [cd] NO)"];`

But the performance is very very slow. Is there a way to make it easier and faster?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using string attributes instead of integer/boolean ones? What are the possible values for `strasse.checks`, `raumattribute.schalter` and `strasse.standort.ortcheck`?

Comment: strasse.checks, raumattribute.schalter and strasse.standort.ortcheck are NSSet's of bool values

Comment: What do you run the predicate on? a fetch request or an array of objects? Where does that array come?

Comment: I run it on a fetch request.   Look at that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027357/complex-predicate-with-to-many-relationship-not-working-correctly. Maybe you understand what my problem ist. its the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify your predicate to look like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
 @"(raumattribute.schalter CONTAINS YES OR raumattribute.schalter CONTAINS NO) AND \
 (strasse.checks CONTAINS YES OR strasse.standort.ortcheck CONTAINS YES) OR \
 strasse.standort.ortcheck CONTAINS NO"];
```

Then, if we assume `raumattribute.schalter` and `strasse.standort.ortcheck` contain boolean values only, we can simplify the predicate again:

```
NSPredicate *predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
 @"raumattribute.schalter.@count > 0 AND \
 (strasse.checks CONTAINS YES OR strasse.standort.ortcheck.@count > 0) OR \
 strasse.standort.ortcheck CONTAINS NO"];
```

Comment: If i try your first simplify, the predicate does not filter anything. If i try the second xcode throws an exception : unsupported function expression  raumattribute.schalter[SIZE]

Comment: I replaced `[SIZE]` with `@count`. I think it should solve the exception.