# Complex predicate with to-many relationship not working correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

I have an app where i can search for a room to book it.

In my first view I can select a city and the street.
In the second view I can select some attributes (like wlan, tv...)

In the 3rd view are the rooms that are available to the selection.

When I don't select an attribute, it should show me all the rooms that are available for the selected street/city.

Here is my predicate so far:

```
   NSPredicate *predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
 @"((raumattribute.schalter CONTAINS YES) AND\
 (strasse.checks CONTAINS YES OR strasse.standort.ortcheck CONTAINS YES)) \
 OR\
 ((raumattribute.schalter CONTAINS NO) AND\
 (strasse.checks CONTAINS YES OR strasse.standort.ortcheck CONTAINS YES))"];
```

The problem is, i can't filter the rooms anymore with the attributes. When I select the city and go to the rooms, I can see all the rooms in the city. 
But as soon as I select an attribute it doesn't filter the rooms, but shows all the rooms in the selected city.

When I write my predicate like this:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate =

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
 @"((raumattribute.schalter CONTAINS YES) AND\
 (strasse.checks CONTAINS YES OR strasse.standort.ortcheck CONTAINS YES))
```

I can filter the rooms with the streets and the attributes. .But when no attribute is selected, I can't see any room in the selected street.

here is a Screenshot of my updated schema: [Screenshot](http://i41.tinypic.com/2z7qw3s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking the core-data framework, which is an object graph, with an SQL database substitute. This can be debated *ad nauseam* so let's not get into a philosophical discussion.

The proper way to do this **from your problem description** is to filter the rooms by street and then **iterate** through the result to exclude those that do not have the checked attributes. The resulting array could be the `datasource` of your resulting table.

However, from your **code examples** and the German entity and attribute names I am observing, it seems that you should perhaps consider revising your data structure. If you edit your question and also post your data model scheme I can give you further comments.

Comment: The screenshot is not complete. Very confusing. For fixing the display bug, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026349/xcode-data-model-problems-with-appearance-in-editor/10028027#10028027).